# Is there a way to see/manage all users, channels in a dashboard or CLI?

Tags: getstream-io

We've created countless test channels and users while testing and setting up Stream Chat, but we aren't seeing a way to see or manage those objects ... for example when we want to delete them.

Is there a dashboard or CLI we can use to manage everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/getstream-cli and its repo
https://github.com/getstream/stream-cli should be able to handle most of your needs.

If there is a missing feature, feel free to open an issue to discuss.